# How to do a MondoID aggregation on related document

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I'm using MongoDB and MongoID. I have relationship of documents such as `has_many` between model `Campaign` and `Media` where `Campaign belongs_to Media`.

I'd like to make an aggregation on Campaign where I get a value from Media. I'm trying the following:

```
results = Campaign.collection.aggregate [
    { '$match': { "state": 'active' } },
    { '$group': {
      '_id': { budget: "$media.budget", date: "$date" },
      'budget': { '$sum': { 'media': '$budget' } }
      }
    }
  ]
```

Where I'd like to get the total budget of Model Media which has a property called `budget`. The above is not working. Any idea on how to make it work?